# MediaElement.js and Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, html5-video, mediaelement.js

My videos on Amazon S3 will not play through MediaElement.js. I get a black video player with the 'Download File' link.  This behavior is consistent on Firefox and Chrome with a variety of video formats (MP4, MOV, OGG).

For each video, the mime type is set correctly on S3 (i.e. *not* `application/octet-stream`).  When moved to my own server, the same videos load and play fine through MediaElement.js.

In Firebug > Net, I see a GET request status that returns `206 Partial Content` for each video loading from S3. I tried appending a timestamp to the URLs to bust the cache, but that didn't work.

I've Googled quite a bit, but came up empty-handed. Any idea what might be the problem?

Update: I get the exact same result using Video.js, so it's obviously not limited to MediaElement.js.

Comment: Can you show your video element in HTML? This way one can help better.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem using S3 with CloudFront. Any updates?

Comment: same here - but only for some videos. others work fine :(

Comment: I gave this problem as well :(